# Using jQuery Ajax inside php echo statement

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to echo some javascript and jquery ajax code inside a php statement and sending a mysql query from jquery ajax. I input the names of users and a send friend request button in front of them dynamically, just like in Facebook.

A small portion of code is given below and I cannot understand why it is not working. No statement in request.php file is executed and no change occurs in database whatsoever.

```
echo '<input type = "button" id = "' . $data['user_id'] . '" value = "Send Friend 
Request" onClick = "send_request(this.id);"/>' ;
```

There is no problem at all the with the above html or concatenation. It is absolutely fine. I am using it inside the function. Just the ajax part is not working.
Here is the php code. request.php contains just a query to the database after connection is made.

```
echo "<script type = 'text/javascript'>" ;
echo "function send_request(_id)
val = document.getElementById(_id).value ;
if (val == 'Send Friend Request')
  val = 'Cancel Friend Request' ;
else
 val = 'Send Friend Request' ;
document.getElementById(_id).value = val ;

$.ajax
(
{
 type: 'post',
 url: 'request.php',
 data: {id: _id}
}
) ;
}" ;
echo "</script>" ;
```

**request.php**

```
$id = $_POST['id'] ;
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'] ;
$query = "INSERT INTO friend (friend_id, user_id) VALUES ('$id', '$userid')" ;
$result = mysql_query($query)
```

Comment: Why are you putting all your JS in php tags? Why isn't it in its own JS file?

Comment: Because I am outputting html dynamically. You will notice that the input tag is echoed as well.

Comment: Your concatenation seems to be broken here `id = "' . {$data['user_id']} . '"`

Comment: There is no problem in there. id is reaching fine there. I am using it in DOM element.

Comment: @Sasha give us some more code from request.php. May be problem is somewhere else.,may be the query has a problem?

Comment: There is no reason to echo out static scripts, it is an absolute pain to work with javscript encapsed in php strings (No syntax highlighting by the IDE for the javascript, concatenation can go wrong, etc etc.). As @bzupnick said you should really put it in a seperate file, or just dont echo it out, its not "dynamic" its dumb.

Comment: I cant figure out a way to do that. I echo the input button under an if condition. So I guess I would have to do it this way. Is there a better way than that?

Answer (score 0):

The best answer would be to put it in it's own JS file, and call it dynamically on the click of that button.

Comment: I wish I could. But the button has to be generated under an if condition, not otherwise.

Comment: You can have the button generated by an if statement, but the JavaScript that is ran when the button is clicked, can always sit there.

Comment: As the button is echoed, it cannot call javascript in a .js file.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a { after the function definition line where you echo the dynamic Javascript.

Comment: I cant seem to find it. There are 3 { and 3 }.

Comment: After this line in your code block above:
echo "function send_request(_id) 
It could be that it didn't show in the code block.
Have you tried running your code in Firefox and using Firebug to debug it. That is what I usually do with my code, to see if any of the Javascript is not working correctly.